# How to arrange the data for a heatmap pcolormesh?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

All the examples I've been turning up use random data.  My problem is arranging my actual data to fit the solution.

I'm trying to create a heatmap/scatterplot of x,y,z: x and y are the position, whilst z is the color. 
They're in three arrays of equal length.

```
X = [-0.11, -0.06, -0.07, -0.12, ...]
Y = [0.09, 0.13, 0.17, 0.09, ...]
Z = [0.38, 0.37, 0.44, 0.33, ...]
```

The [pcolormesh documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh) doesn't seem to describe what "C" is other than to say it can be a "masked array".  Sadly I don't know what that is either (yet).

How do I turn my three arrays into whatever it's looking for? I tried sticking them into a numpy array and passing that, which quieted the error about no "shape", but a three dimensional array doesn't seem to be what it's looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pcolormesh` wants three 2-D arrays.

your `X` and `Y` are fine, but need to be run through numpy's `meshgrid` function, i.e.:

```
import numpy as np
X = [-0.11, -0.06, -0.07, -0.12, ...]
Y = [0.09, 0.13, 0.17, 0.09, ...]
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
```

then you just need to get `Z` to be in a shape that is the same as `xx` and `yy` and you'll be all set.

For the scatter plot, `X`, `Y`, and, `Z` are fine:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
X = [-0.11, -0.06, -0.07, -0.12, ...]
Y = [0.09, 0.13, 0.17, 0.09, ...]
Z = [0.38, 0.37, 0.44, 0.33, ...]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(X, Y, c=Z)
plt.show()
```

Comment: aw crap... I remember now I got that result hours ago but quickly dismissed it as impossible. Thanks.  A case of not seeing what I was expecting.  I hope it's right 'cause someone is in for a big surprise here ;-) checking... double checking... triple...